# Why is my dynamic spinner not populating

Tags: android, dynamic, spinner

I have created a spinner dynamically. It shows up but is empty. It is meant to contain the following string array.

```
<string-array name="task_array">
      <item>task 1</item>
      <item>task 2</item>
      <item>task 3</item>
      <item>task 4</item>    
    </string-array>
```

The following is my code from a class that extends fragmentactivity

```
public void addNewView() {
        final TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.spLayout);
        Spinner sp = new Spinner(this);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_tasks = ArrayAdapter.
                createFromResource(this, R.array.task_array,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        table.addView(sp);
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        sp.setId(i+10);

    }}
```

Any ideas? ta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add the adapter to the spinner.

Use `sp.setAdapter(adapter_tasks);`